# Digitar matriz e exibir menor/maior e suas posições

Tags: python-3.x

Fiz o seguinte código que gera a matriz com valores aleatórios conforme as dimensões são passadas, e traz o resultado do menor valor e sua posição e o maior valor e sua posição.
Ao invés de passar as dimensões da matriz e ela ser gerada, gostaria de digitar cada valor da matriz, separados por espaços em branco. Se a primeira linha for vazia, exibir a mensagem de que está vazio.
Digitando os valores da matriz, exibir a matriz final digitada e seus respectivos menor e maior valor e suas posições.

Não é definido o tamanho da matriz, se é 4x4 por exemplo. É digitado a quantidade que quiser.

Atualmente o código está assim:

```
def generate(numLins, numCols, mn, mx):
    from random import randint
    values = [None] * numLins
    for i in range(numLins):
        values[i] = [0] * numCols
        for j in range(numCols):
            values[i][j] = randint(mn, mx)
    return values


def reveal(values, linMn, linMx, colMn, colMx):
    for i in range(linMn, linMx):
        for j in range(colMn, colMx):
            print(values[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
    print()
    return None

def localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(vals):
    resp = (0, 0)
    for lin in range(len(vals)):
        for col in range(len(vals[lin])):
            if vals[lin][col] > vals[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
                resp = (lin, col)
    return resp


def localizaCelulaComMenorValor(vals):
    resp = (0, 0)
    for lin in range(len(vals)):
        for col in range(len(vals[lin])):
            if vals[lin][col] < vals[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
                resp = (lin, col)
    return resp


print("Dimensões da Matriz:")
dimensoes = input().split()
numLins = int(dimensoes[0])
numCols = int(dimensoes[1])


valores = generate(numLins, numCols, 10, 99)
reveal(valores, 0, numLins, 0, numCols)


ondeMaior = localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(valores)
print("Maior Valor:", valores[ondeMaior[0]][ondeMaior[1]], "na posição: (", ondeMaior[0], ",", ondeMaior[1], ")")

ondeMenor = localizaCelulaComMenorValor(valores)
print("Menor Valor:", valores[ondeMenor[0]][ondeMenor[1]], "na posição: (",ondeMenor[0],",",ondeMenor[1],")" )
```

Comment: Essa resposta utiliza o tamanho da matriz fixo. No meu caso, não é

Comment: Nesse caso, é só colocar a dimensão inserida pelo usuário nos limites da iteração. No exemplo dado, foi uma matriz 4x4. No seu caso, vai ser uma matriz dimensoes[0]xdimensoes[1].

Comment: Onde no código da possível duplicata está range(4), vai ser range(int(dimensoes[0])) ou range(int(dimensoes[1])).

Comment: Tentei rodar o código aqui e não está funcionando. Por ser iniciante, pode ser uma falha minha também.

Comment: Pegue o exemplo do outro post e tente implementá-lo, pois ele está bem menos verborrágico e já teve solução. Depois, nos mostre os erros aqui para que possamos ajudá-lo. :)